# How does the Girl-Genius web-comic relate to the Agatha H. books?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, girl-genius

After spending some time reading [Girl-Genius web-comic](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com) I was convinced to buy the book.

I've ordered what I think is the [first book](http://amzn.com/1597802115) in my local bookstore (yay local) and it seems to relate to the first one or two years of of web content, but I can't be sure.

My question is: "**how does the book series line up with the Web comic?**"  Does it contain specific episodes/adventures, relate to strips from a specific time-span or is it simply an assortment of episodes?

UPDATE:
They are amazing.  It is interplanetary war in the introduction!!!!  Yes!

Comment: Wow.  Intention vs. inference.  I'm asking about something complex, so the question has to be less specific.

Comment: Continually playing with the wording isn't gonna make these on topic. Your most recent edit has simply added the off-topic questions to the **two** on-topic questions. As an aide, I'll edit the question to something workable and you can decide whether you want to keep it that way or roll it back (in which case it'll get closed again).

Comment: @Richard - those "bizarro" departures are a major detractor to the web content.  I want to know if those are in the book.

Comment: Great, that should definitely be your next *new* question. If you have multiple queries, don't be afraid of asking multiple questions.

Comment: Richard - there have been a very few questions for which my personal answers were (imho) amazing.  Here is one: (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158767/why-use-extreme-value-theory/158862#158862)  I want to give others the opportunity to give amazing answers.  I'm not trying to "generate discussion" as much as give opportunity for great.  I will ask other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The webcomic breaks itself up into volumes, each covering roughly 120 pages or around a year of the comic. Each volume usually moves the story forward multiple times, but the breaks between bigger parts of the story tends to follow every 3rd volume.

The novelizations so far follow the "major break" pattern:

- Agatha H and the Airship City covers Volumes 1 thru 3
- Agatha H and the Clockwork Princess covers Volumes 4 thru 6
- Agatha H and the Voice of the Castle extends the pattern a bit to end on a different cliffhanger than Volume 9 does, so it's 7 thru 9 with a chunk o' ten

The next major break in the plot would probably be the end of Volume 13 (also considered end of Act One of the webcomic series - only the Foglios could consider years of webcomics to be "got started") so when they continue the novels, I would expect that to be the next endpoint.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer correctly explains which volumes are covered by each book I thought I'd move my answer over here about how to find which volumes are which on the webcomic.

Under each page of the graphic novel, there's a dropdown with the different chapters listed including a line item for each volume number.

Here's an image of where to see the volume numbers in the dropdown on the chapter selection menu on the [Girl Genius website](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20041004#.VgiV7ntBDoU):

[image: Girl Genius]

This should make it simple to see which volume you're reading and find which pages relate to which of the books in the novelization of the graphic novel. By the way, the link to the GG site above is the link to page one of volume four.