# Are there fluff chapters in the Agatha H. books that are consistent with web-comic "excursions"?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, girl-genius

Reference to related question: [link.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103168/how-does-the-girl-genius-web-comic-relate-to-the-agatha-h-books)

After spending some time reading [Girl-Genius web-comic](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com) I was convinced to buy the book.

I've ordered what I think is the [first book](http://amzn.com/1597802115) in my local bookstore (yay local) and it seems to relate to the first one or two years of of web content, but I can't be sure.

While I love the main storyline and the main characters, one of the things that I liked least about the webcomic was its departures into the bizarre.  One example is when several of the characters are stuck in a shrinking castle and being attacked by a duck.  It had no origin, no closure, and no real link to the main story.  This one, and others like it, seem to be the web-comic version of the ["Bizarro Episode"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BizarroEpisode) tv-trope.

My question is: Do the books contain "bizarro chapters" that, while consistent with the web-comic, depart significantly from the flow of the main storyline or the development of the plot?

There is a tvtrope called a "bizarro episode" ([link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BizarroEpisode))

Comment: A quick scan of the first three books shows no references to a shrinking castle or a duck

Comment: I think your links are messed up. Do you mean *Agatha H and the Airship City*?

Comment: I haven't read the books in a year or so but, as far as I remember, the "filler" from the web comic is not included (unless it's actually part of the story), which the example you cite does not seem to be... if you could link to the Girl Genius pages where it occurs, that might help.

Comment: http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20140101
http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20140117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

So far with 3 books published, no side-story material from the comic has been included, and no original side-stories were created.  Only the main plot is focused on. This doesn't rule out such diversions in the future, however, the authors use the comic as the primary story telling medium, so when they feel the urge to divert it will typically be there.

There are prologues that could be considered brand new sections, but they are directly related to the plot, so I doubt they fall under what you're asking.

Comment: So far - its going pretty darn good.  I just got the whole cat thing.  Dogs have masters, cats have servants.  And those bears with the train - they were the last secret.