# Which sections of the webcomic/graphic novel are covered by "Agatha H. and the Clockwork Princess"

Tags: books, girl-genius

After spending some time reading [Girl-Genius web-comic](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com) I was convinced to buy the [first book](http://amzn.com/1597802115) and I loved it!

The book spanned the time from the beginning to when Agatha escaped the Airship City.  She has not yet been in the wilderness, met the carnival or anything else.

What range of webcomic story does the next book, "[Agatha H. and the Clockwork Princess](http://amzn.com/1597802239)" cover?  I'm hoping it starts from the end of the first book and goes on until she is close to castle Heterodyne.  I would like a confirmation whether or not this is the case.

Comment: Is there a reason [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103240/41668) to your previous question doesn't answer this one? It seems quite clear to me. "*Agatha H and the Clockwork Princess covers Volumes 4 thru 6*".

Comment: I missed that part.  Also ... I'm not exactly sure what volume 6 is.  I'm sure I can web-search for it.  Thanks.

Comment: It's on the website. The dropdown at the bottom of every page has each chapter titled and ordered by volume number.

Comment: If it is so downvoted - I can just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

As the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103240/41668) said, "*Agatha H and the Clockwork Princess covers Volumes 4 thru 6*"

Here's an image of where to see the volume numbers in the dropdown on the chapter selection menu on the [Girl Genius website](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20041004#.VgiV7ntBDoU):

[image: Girl Genius]

This should make it simple to see which volume you're reading and find volumes 4-6. By the way, the link to the GG site above is the link to page one of vloume four.

Comment: I read this end to end and never saw the interface.  While it may be gaslamp or steam-punk, the user-interface has some room for improvement.  A single "how to use this site" link for newbies would go a long way.  You might consider A/B testing to get a true measure of how new or old readers even know about that particular interface.  It would give you data.

Comment: @EngrStudent you who? You say that as if I'm associated with GG... I'm not. I figured it out on my own.

Comment: They will see it, eventually, and read it.

Comment: @EngrStudent They will? Huh? I'd honestly be surprised if they are even aware what SE is... You know, they have a contact us link on their site, too... you could just tell them directly. They're very nice people.